# .gitlab-ci.yml to include multiple shell functions from multiple yml files

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

I have a Gitlab mono repository with some backend Java and frontend Node.js code. To create a CI, I'm working on a shared approach to build both the applications.

In the application repository, let's call it "A", I have source code as well a .gitlab-ci.yml file as below,

```
A
├── .gitlab-ci.yml
├── backendapi
└── ui
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml** file,

```
---
include: 
  - project: 'root/B'
    ref: master
    file: 'top-level.yml'

  - project: 'root/B'
    ref: master
    file: 'maven.yml'

  - project: 'root/B'
    ref: master
    file: 'node.yml'
```

I have another repository called "B", where I have all my CI functionalities in three different files.

```
B
├── maven.yml
├── node.yml
└── top-level.yml
```

1. **top-level.yml** file that has my build stage in it,

```
---
stages:
  - build

variables:
  GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY: "1"

.build_script: &build_script
  stage: build
  tags:
    - default
    - docker

java_build:
  <<: *build_script
  image: 
    name: maven:latest
  script:
    - backend_build

node_build:
  <<: *build_script
  image: 
    name: node:slim
  script:
    - frontend_build
```

2. **maven.yml**, that has mvn build function,

```
.maven_build: &maven_build |-
  function backend_build {
    cd backendapi
    mvn clean package -DskipTests
  }

before_script:
  - *maven_build
```

3. **node.yml**, with node function in it,

```
.node_build: &node_build |-
  function frontend_build {
    cd ui
    npm install
    npm build
  }

before_script:
  - *node_build
```

When the **.gitlab-ci.yml** file in repository "A" is run, it is calling the **top-level.yml**, **maven.yml** and **node.yml** files from the repository "B" which is good.

> The problem here is when it runs the **java_build** it is unable to find the **backend_build** function from **maven.yml** instead it seems like it only loading the **frontend_build** function from **node.yml** file or overwriting the **backend_build** function from **maven.yml** file. The **node_build** works as expected, cause it can find the **frontend_build** function.

```
the Skipping Git submodules setup
Authenticating with credentials from /root/.docker/config.json
Authenticating with credentials from /root/.docker/config.json
Authenticating with credentials from /root/.docker/config.json
$ function frontend_build { # collapsed multi-line command
$ backend_build
/bin/bash: line 90: backend_build: command not found
```

I know that I can copy all the functions into one big yml file in repository "B" and include the in .gitlab-ci.yml in the repository "A" but here I'm trying to understand is it even possible to try the above approach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's strange naming. `node.yml` -> `node_build` -> `before_script` -> `frontend_build` (only declaration) -> `script` ->` fontend_build` (call), why so many chains? Why not just `.frontend_build: &frontend_build |-` inside `node.yml` and then `script: - *frontend_build`?

Comment: jobs in a given stage tend to run in _parallel_ so if you have a job that depends on the completion of previous jobs, I recommend moving the job (java_build) to a build2 stage or whatever you want to name it

Comment: @KamilCuk I posted the answer or hack below. Thank you for responding.

Comment: @Arty-chan I posted the answer or hack below. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Finally found a hack but not a complete answer as yaml files cannot act accordingly as I stated in my question, but I took a different approach to solve the problem.

Well, there are no more maven.yml or node.yml, there are only four files in the repository `B` `backend.yml`, `frontend.yml`, `hybrid.yml` and `top-level.yml`.

The backend.yml has all the functions (build_app, lint_app, unit_test_app and so on..) that are required and the same follows the frontend.yml with different commands in the functions.

ex: In the backend.yml build_app function I will have the maven command at the same time in the `frontend.yml` build_app function I will have the nom command. Here the build_app function name is common in both the frontend.yml and backend.yml but the functionality is different.

In the top-level.yml stages, I specified the common function name as build_app in the script key.

```
stages:
  - build

variables:
  GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY: "1"

.build_script: &build_script
  stage: build
  tags:
    - default
    - docker

build:
  <<: *build_script
  image: maven:latest
  script:
    - build_app
```

But in the .gitlab-ci.yml, depending on the build I need to do, I include that specific yml file. In the below example I want to build the backend and included the backend.yml same applies for the frontend.

```
include: 
  - project: 'root/B'
    ref: master
    file: 'top-level.yml'

  - project: 'root/B'
    ref: master
    file: 'backend.yml'
```

If I have to build both the backend and frontend, I will use a hybrid.yml with the same function name as build_app but include both the maven and npm command. I know this is not the right approach but I will suffice the use case I'm trying to solve.

Thank you for helping me with the question!

Happy Automation :)