# Does gitlab-ci have a way to download a script and store it on the local file system so it could be run?

Tags: gitlab-ci

Does gitlab-ci have a way to download a script and store it on the local file system so it could be run?  Looks like other's have asked similar questions (see below).

One way to do it would be to use curl (but curl has to exist in the CI runner):

```
curl -o ./myscript -k https://example.com/myscript.sh
```

This was from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22800194/3281336.

If I have a script that I would like to use in multiple CI-pipelines, I'd like to have a way to download the script to the local file system to use in the pipeline.  NOTE: I don't have the ability to create a custom runner or docker image in my given situation.

If the script were available via git or an https website, what are my alternatives?

### Some search results

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html - Gitlab supports a way to include files, even from GIT repos.  This might work I just haven't read how.
- [How to run a script from file in another project using include in GitLab CI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63693061/how-to-run-a-script-from-file-in-another-project-using-include-in-gitlab-ci) - Similar but the answer uses a multi-project pipeline and a trigger which is really (I think) a different answer.
- [.gitlab-ci.yml to include multiple shell functions from multiple yml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58150822/gitlab-ci-yml-to-include-multiple-shell-functions-from-multiple-yml-files) - Similar but the question is dealing with scripts in YAML files and I'm dealing with a stand alone script.
- [How to include a PowerShell script file in a GitLab CI YAML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59794871/how-to-include-a-powershell-script-file-in-a-gitlab-ci-yaml-file) - So far this is the closest to my question and some might consider it *the same* even though the question is asking about a powershell script.  The answer said this wasn't possible to include a script (so maybe this is not possible using the GitLab CI syntax).

If it is possible, please let me know how to do this.

Comment: I am not sure if I really understand your question. At least I do not have a clear picture about your use-case, because I feel it is much easier: 1. Put the script in a Git repository and host it on GitLab. 2. Install GitLab Runner on the machine where you want to run your script and [register a runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/) using the tokens from your GitLab repository. 3. Configure your jobs in the `gitlab-ci.yml`. Now, when you run a job the GitLab Runner will fetch your repository and thus your script and you can define to run the script within the `gitlab-ci.yml`.

Comment: I understand.  If I could do the things you suggest, I believe that would solve my problem, but I'm not authorized to modify the gitlab-ci images and runners.